# Fetching values and sending in an array

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

I have fetched some integer values from getAPI:

```
List<String> jsonResponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
        if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals("agent_sms_missed_call")) {
            agentMissedCallId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
        if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals("caller_sms_missed_call")) {
            callerMissedCallSmsId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to send the value of agentMissedCallId and callerMissedCallSmsId  in PUT API : How can i acheive that .

```
{
 "sms_template": [
      idFetched(agentMissedCallId), idFetched(callerMissedCallSmsId)
     ]
 }
```

Response I am getting from a GET API :

```
[
  {
    "id": 29169,
    "name": "Template 1",
    "type": "agent_sms_missed_call"
  },
  {
    "id": 29170,
    "name": "Template 2",
    "type": "caller_sms_missed_call"
  }
]
```

Request body I want :

```
{
  "sms_template": [
    29169
  ],
  "name": "Hello ",
  "destination": "hangup||1",
  "description": "number for department"
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the response and your expected request body you want to make?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 Response I am getting : [
    {
        "id": 29169,
        "name": "Template 1",
        "type": "agent_sms_missed_call"
    },
    {
        "id": 29170,
        "name": "Template 2",
        "type": "caller_sms_missed_call"} ]                                                                                       Request body I want : {
     "sms_template": [
          29169
     ],
     "name": "Hello ",
     "destination": "hangup||1",
     "description": "number for department"
}

Comment: please update thoes info to your question.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 please check

Answer (score 0):

This below approach is not recommended, but it doesn't require any 3rd lib, so I think it works for you.

```
Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
body.put("sms_template", List.of(agentMissedCallId, callerMissedCallSmsId));
body.put("name", "Hello ");
body.put("destination", "hangup||1");
body.put("description", "number for department");

given().log().body().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .body(body)
        .post("https://postman-echo.com/post");
```